# Asp.Net MVC Master Detail view using kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid, telerik-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to create contacts view. My model is:

```
public class Contact
{
    public Contact()
    {
        Documents = new HashSet<Document>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public Document() { }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentNo { get; set; }
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileContent { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int ContentLength { get; set; }
}
```

I have created view with Contact details and Grid for documents. Actually I am new to MVC so I am searched internet how to achieve this. But I cannot find any workable solution yet. I do not know how to add one or more document and persist document details in grid.  What I am trying to achieve is save contact information with uploaded documents (one or more) while submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to achieve what you desire, using a parent child combination.
The below code is just a sample providing a view only option to detail view.

```
@model Models.Contact

<div id="ModelView">
          <div >@Html.Label("Name")</div>
          <div >
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
          </div>
          ...
          ...

  <div id="grid"></div>
</div>

<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        data: model.Documents,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                fields: {
                                    //append fiels as per your document model
                                    FileName: { type: "string" },
                                    DocumentType: { type: "number" }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: 20
                    },
                    dataBound: OnDataBound
                    height: 550,
                    scrollable: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    columns: [
                        "FileName",
                        { field: "FileName", title: "File Name", width: "130px", clientTemplate: "<input type='file' name='docs'/>" },
                        { field: "DocumentType", title: "Document Type", width: "130px" }
                    ]
                });
            });

 function OnDataBound(e){
   $('[name=docs]').kendoUpload(
 {
     async: 
         {
            saveUrl: ......
            removeUrl: ........
            autoUpload: true
        },
        upload: onUpload, //Your custom function for uploader
        success: onSuccess //Write the below function to display approprate message
 }); 
 }
 </script>
```

Note: Above code will upload documents one by One rather than all documents at once, just for load balancing.

Comment: Actually, I have a view with single contact model and grid for documents. My question is how do I use upload control inside grid and post it with submit event. I want to upload more than one files.

Comment: Yes you can achieve the same from above, the only difference would be that you will need to specify separate Create/update/read controller for Document Model for better control over insertion and updation.

Comment: @Arun I assume you are not viewing the Contacts model in the Grid as I shown, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I am not using grid for contacts model. Suppose if I use separate controller for Document model how it will link with ContactId (foreign key) ? Because contact id is created after inserting into database.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve above using different controllers, but if you want to go with your current structure then also above code will work. The only js function you need to add will be **onSuccess** in which you will need to add the Document information from the upload file into the Grid so the information is captured by the master Model (Contact Model)